# iRedmail: Email lands in SPAM for Hotmail

Tags: dns, spf, email-spam, iredmail

I am running a webserver hosting two domains (domain1, domain2). Further, I am using iRedmail as the mailserver. I can receive emails for both domains, however, when I try to send a mail from either of the two domains, the mail lands in the SPAM folder when the receiver address is a hotmail address but not when the receiver address is from Google.

I have the following DNS-Entries for the two domains:

For Domain1:

```
mail.domain1    86400   A   0   THE-IP
domain1         86400   A   0   THE-IP
domain1         86400   MX  10  mail.domain1
domain1         86400   TXT 0   v=spf1 a mx a:mail-relay.contabo.net include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

For Domain2:

```
mail.domain2    86400   A   0   THE-IP
domain2         86400   A   0   THE-IP
domain2         86400   MX  10  mail.domain2
domain2         86400   TXT 0   v=spf1 a mx a:mail-relay.contabo.net include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing?" — A programming related question. You might be on topic over on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

New domains have at least a 6 month warming period before they start hitting the inbox in Hotmail. You might be able to accelerate that, by having your IP's mitigated via through a ticket with Microsoft sender support. You also need to have everything else set up correctly on your domain.

Take a look at this [Email Deliverability Guide](https://www.zerobounce.net/guide-to-improve-inbox-and-delivery.html)

Here's the form for Microsoft Mitigation to full out: [Microsoft Sender Support](https://support.microsoft.com/oas/oasp_handler?redirectOnError=1&oasp_formaction=https%253a%252f%252foisxsvc.support.microsoft.com%252fcapsub_12.0.0.0%252fworkflow%252fdefaultworkflow&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us&forceorigin=esmc&ccsid=636586647103785610&stepid=1)

You're SPF looks fine for a redacted version.